# Absolute convergence of sum of convolutions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

How do you prove that suppose

$\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge absolutely, then the series $\sum c_n$ also converges absolutely where $c_n = a_1b_{n-1} + a_2b_{n-2} + \cdots + a_{n-1}b_1$

Answer (score 2):

You can see this by [Fubini-Tonelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). Namely, with nonnegative coefficients, every formal manipulation is legal. Sometimes it leads to $+\infty=+\infty$, but that's still true:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|c_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}|a_k||b_{n-k}|=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}|a_k||b_{n-k}|=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}|a_k|\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}|b_{n-k}|=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}|a_k|\sum_{l=1}^{+\infty}|b_{l}|.
$$

Interestingly, it suffices that one of the two series converges absolutely, and that the other one converges conditionally to obtain convergence and equality:
$$
\sum a_n\sum b_n=\sum c_n.
$$ 
See [Mertens' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that the $a_i$ and $b_j$ are non-negative. Fix $N$ an integer. Then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^na_jb_{n-j}=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{n=j}^Na_jb_{n-j}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^Na_j\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}b_k\leqslant 
\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}a_k\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}b_k.$$